# play store google account - related android phones

Tags: android, google-play

If I have a google play account which is related to many mobile phone , if I installed an app to all my devices is that means that every installation is counted in google play devoleper console or it is counted as one installation?

Comment: Pls Go through [How to Ask on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking first query

Answer (score 0):

In Google Play Console you have two types of statistic. You can see the information both on devices and on users

[image: google play console statistics]